# min,max value of $x^4+y^4+z^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

for positive real number x,y,z
$x+y+z=4$ , $xyz=2$. now, get the minimum and maximum value of  $x^4+y^4+z^4$.

**attempt**
i tried to use c.s.i and AM-GM inequality. However, it was hard to make the x,y,z's value same in all inequalities.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%2By%2Bz%3D4%2Cxyz%3D2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5E4%2By%5E4%2Bz%5E4%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aminimum%2C%20OR%20content%3Amaximum&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1355499p7414492), but it only deals with trying to find the minimum value.

Comment: Also note that the aops thread does not have the restriction $x,y,z>0$

Comment: sorry but i am getting hard time through understanding the aops solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the initial ideas of the first solution on the AOPS thread (though there are errors in that one). We let $k=xy+yz+xz$ and then we express $x^4+y^4+z^4$ in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials of $x,y,z$. We can derive that
$$x^4+y^4+z^4=2k^2-64k+288$$
Note that $k>0$ because it is the sum of $3$ positive numbers and that $k<8$ since $(x+y+z)^2-2k=x^2+y^2+z^2>0$. Since $2k^2-64k+288$ is decreasing for $k\in (0,8)$ (it's a upward parabola with a vertex having x coordinate of $16$). It suffices to find the maximum and minimum value of $k$.

From here we can use lagrange multipliers. Critical points occur at the solutions to
$$\begin{cases}y+z-\lambda_1-\lambda_2yz=0\\
x+z-\lambda_1-\lambda_2xz=0\\
x+y-\lambda_1-\lambda_2xy=0\\
x+y+z=4\\
xyz=2\\
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}4-x-\lambda_1-\frac{2\lambda_2}{x}=0\\
4-y-\lambda_1-\frac{2\lambda_2}{y}=0\\
4-z-\lambda_1-\frac{2\lambda_2}{z}=0\\
x+y+z=4\\
xyz=2\\
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}x^2+(\lambda_1-4)x+2\lambda_2=0\\
y^2+(\lambda_1-4)y+2\lambda_2=0\\
z^2+(\lambda_1-4)z+2\lambda_2=0\\
x+y+z=4\\
xyz=2\\
\end{cases}$$
So essentially $x,y,z$ are real positive roots of this quadratic. Since a quadratic has $2$ distinct roots, any critical point must occur when WLOG $x=y$. We can eliminate $y$ and we have the equations
$$\begin{cases}2x+z=4\\x^2z=2\end{cases}$$
Substituting $z=4-2x$ we have that
$$x^2(4-2x)=2$$
$$2x^3-4x^2+2=0$$
$$(2x-2)(x^2-x-1)=0$$
So either $x=1$ or $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. In the first case we have $z=2$ which gives $k=5$. In the second case we have $z=3-\sqrt{5}$ which gives $k=\frac{-1+5\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 5.09$.

So the minimum value of $k$ is $5$ which is associated with a maximum value of $x^4+y^4+z^4=\boxed{18}$

So the maximum value for $k$ is $\frac{-1+5\sqrt{5}}{2}$ which is associated with a minimum value of $x^4+y^4+z^4=\boxed{383-165\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: Do you spend more time with these types of contest problems as opposed studying standard pure mathematics?

Comment: @Ganyuuenjoyer me personally, I did a lot of contest problems in high school back when I did contests. Now I'm in college and am doing an additional math major. I just like to lurk in these places to answer questions that I find interesting or am able to do.

Comment: For finding the extrema for $k$, it is enough to consider $(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2 \geqslant 0$ which gives an easily factorable cubic in $k$ and hence a nice interval for allowable $k$.

Comment: @Macavity Is the easily factorable cubic you are referring to $\prod_{cyc} \left(16-2k-x-\frac{4}{x}\right)$? Or am I missing something. I don't really see how to continue.

Comment: @AlanAbraham The discriminant mentioned is a symmetric polynomial, so you can proceed using elementary symmetric polynomials to get $(k-5)(k^2+k-31)\leqslant 0$.  The two positive roots of LHS then give you the end points of the desired interval, and hence extrema.